# Extracting an object diagram to a class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, object-diagram

Below, is the mapping of class diagram to object diagram correct? I can not seem to find a useful tutorial on object diagrams anywhere!

Here is the image [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technically  Your Object Diagram is True**

Object diagrams are not used much as class diagrams.
[ Although we are doing **Object-Oriented** not **Class-Oriented** Design-Programming, that is irony :-) ]

Object Diagram is simple : Just show objects and the connections between them.

**And All Diagrams Should Have Purpose**

Why to use Object Diagram?

- To make things more explicit? Such as what DataItem can be in real
  life?
- Or you may start with object diagram, then find-discover classes from
  those objects?

**Why you map Class Diagram to Object Diagram?**

Ask, what I will get from  drawing object this diagram,if you have good benefit-reason,
Then you are on the right track. Go on... :-)

**For More Info:**

Object Diagrams are simple. Just look at the book:

The Elements of UML 2.0 Style by Scott Ambler

[ Chapter 13: UML Object diagram guidelines (3 guidelines) ]

Comment: Thanks mate! im sitting an exam on this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I use an eclipse plugin http://www.objectaid.com/ for java applications.

All you have to do is simply select all the classes and drag it into the diagram space, as you update your code in Eclipse, the diagram is updated as well. You can control and easily select what you want to see in the diagrams like relationships, classifiers, attributes, operations etc. They do have a nice [one minute tutorial](https://www.objectaid.com/features.html)

Comment: so is the diagram correct or not?